# MySQL query very slow with 605500 results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
Field       Type          Null       Key                Default Extra
id          int(11)       NO         PRI                NULL    auto_increment
campaignId  int(11)       NO         MUL                NULL    
preview     tinyint(1)    NO         NULL   
pid         varchar(255)  NO         NULL   
ip          int(10)       unsigned   NO                 NULL    
data        longtext      NO         NULL   
created     timestamp     NO         CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

When I use this query:

```
SELECT
    SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * 
FROM
    `participants`
USE INDEX (`indexed fields`)    
WHERE
    `campaignId` = 1
ORDER BY
    `created` DESC
LIMIT
    0,
    1000
```

This query is taking around:

```
Query took 0.6166 sec
```

When I explain this query:

```
id  select_type table           type    possible_keys   key  key_len  ref   rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      participants    ALL     indexed fields  NULL NULL     NULL  605811  Using where; Using filesort
```

I have these indexes:

```
Table       Non_unique  Key_name        Seq_in_index            Column_name Collation   Cardinality Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment Index_comment
participants    0       PRIMARY         1           id          A           605811      NULL        NULL        BTREE       
participants    1       indexed fields  1           campaignId  A           1           NULL        NULL        BTREE       
participants    1       indexed fields  2           created     A           738         NULL        NULL        BTREE
```

I don't really understand the explanation a 100%, but I know that this query is pretty slow.
I have around 605500 results that I need to load at once.
When I use a php script like this (this script is doing the script above multiple times):

```
for($i = 0; $i <= $participants->pageAmount; $i++):
            /*
             * loop through participant pages
             * Create a new sheet (not a new file) for every page of participants
            */
            $pageParticipants   = $this->fetchParticipants($i, $participantsPerPage);
            //$pageParticipants = true;
            echo $i."\n";
            if($pageParticipants === false) break; // no participants are found
            else{
//              $this->createSheet($i);
            }
        endfor;
```

It is already taking `14.3291 seconds` to do the script just 3 times.
I'm wondering how I can speed up this process so I don't have to wait a week before my output is showed.

Comment: Please reformat table structure and indexes with better alignment, it is unreadable right now.

Comment: Use `SELECT EXPLAIN` to see which indexes your query is using right now and adjust them.

Comment: @FIA2008 do you query multiple times the same table with different where condition

Comment: MatteoTassinari, I've improved reading.
TiMESPLiNTER, I've already done that. The results is shown below the query time.
vivek, Yes I do

Comment: @user2864740, I hope the query time can be improved, .6 seconds is quite slow for a thousand records I think. Also, the page on which the results are shown is not taking .6 seconds, but 14 seconds for just 1000 results.